# how could inverse be found of this $x^ne^{x^2}$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, inverse

$f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty), f(x)=x^n e^{x^2}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ I need to find $(f^{-1})'(e)$, also to show $f^{-1}$ is continously differentiable,

First of all I tried to find inverse like this: if $g$ be the inverse then, $f(g(x))\equiv I_{[0,\infty)}=x\Rightarrow (g)^ne^{g^2}=x $ but I think if I take log both side , I can not find explicictly $g$ , pplease help.

Comment: That you cannot find $g$ explicitly is on purpose for this exercise

Comment: Thus spake zarathrustraaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: You can show that $f^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable without finding $f^{-1}$ explicitly by using the inverse function theorem. To find $(f^{-1})'(e)$, try first finding $x$ such that $f(x) = e$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

use 
$$
\left(f^{-1} \right)'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}
$$

---

with $x=e$. And note that $f(1)=e$.

Comment: what is $f^{-1}$ ???????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Note that $f(1)=e$.